# Add a test device for Adwhirl

Tags: android, adwhirl

I have created an account of Adwhirl and add my Admob network to it.I am not displaying any advert when I am using Adwhirl. My logcat says

```
To get test ads on this device, call adRequest.addTestDevice("CF95DC53F383F9A836FD749F3EF439ZW");
```

If I use Admob only I can set it:

```
    adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a14e9698a5e5ww3"); //Test
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();      
    adRequest.addTestDevice("CF95DC53F383F9A836FD749F3EF439ZW");
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

But when using Adwhir, that is not possible:

```
    AdWhirlManager.setConfigExpireTimeout(1000 * 60 * 5);
    AdWhirlTargeting.setTestMode(true);     
    AdWhirlLayout adWhirlLayout = new AdWhirlLayout(this,"74c8934e149649e2a1211cb336f7e0b9"); //test
```

As I cant configure the adRequest as when I use Admob. I thought that setTestMode to true would do the trick, but it doesnt, and actually I dont really know for what is that method, as my app behavies the same that when I set to false.

So basically, how can I get on my screen a test advert with Adwhirl as I do for Admob?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [AdWhirl code](http://code.google.com/p/adwhirl/source/browse/src/com/adwhirl/adapters/GoogleAdMobAdsAdapter.java?repo=sdk-android#74) uses the old setTesting method, which would only set test mode on the emulator.  Therefore it currently does not have support for entering the device id so you will get real ads on your phone.

The code is open source, so you could edit this to use the addTestDevice method and rebuild the jar file.  This is probably worth adding to the adapter out of the box, however.